# Which checkpoint should I select for continue for Object detection training

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, object-detection, training-data

I start to training until ckpt-7 then I stopped training.  Then  again I started training but befor I changed  pipline config in fine tune chekpoint on  my model. I wrote latest check point and I changed  its directory . My loss function approximetly 0.899 before stopped to the training.
When I continue to train but its start to steps 100 and my loss fuction 15.009.

How can I contiune the model before stopped? What should I do?

I am using centernet model with Colab.
Please explain I am new on that topic.

Comment: You can try to use `tf.train.CheckpointManager` at the start. It manages multiple checkpoints by keeping recent checkpoints and deletes old checkpoint. If your model is overfitted then loss will be increased. To reduce try to tune hyperparameters. `mini_batch_size`,`learning_rate` and `optimizer` have the greatest impact on the object detection objective metric .Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could understand your question that you could not resume the training where it stopped.

Actually with the updates in TF2, we need not change the finetune checkpoint parameter in the pipeline.config. Re-run the same training script pointing to the same model_dir where your checkpoints are stored.

TF2 will automatically understand and resume from where the training stopped with the help of checkpoints created in the model_dir.